# Doubt Related to Composite Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a simple doubts related to the specification of Hypothesis. Consider a distribution with only one parameter $\theta$ and let us assume that we are testing $H_0:\theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta \ne \theta_0$. My question is can i alternatively write this same hypothesis as follows:

$H_0:\theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta > \theta_0 \text{ or } \theta < \theta_0$.

Comment: You can: why do you want to?

Comment: There was a problem in my book on uniform distribution. It has three parts. First part is a right tailed test and second part was a left tailed. In the third part, they mentioned the alternative hypothesis as $H_!:\theta \ne \theta_0$. So, I thought if I can write this alternative as mentioned, I would be just able to combine the results from the first two parts.

Comment: Yes, one way of looking at a two-tailed test is as a combination of two one-tailed tests with a correction for multiple comparisons. It might be an idea to present your thinking with regard to this particular problem, as $\theta \neq \theta_0$ trivially implies either $\theta<\theta_0$ or $\theta>\theta_0$ for scalar real $\theta$.